# How do I query (select) on an element not including it's children?

Tags: jsoup

Element.select() returns matched elements that may include this element, or any of its children. Is there any way I can query on this element only but not including it's children?

For example, I want to know whether an element matches a query condition, e.g. "p,li". I know I can use Element.getElementsByxxx() methods, but since the query can be a tag or an attribute or some other conditions, Element.getElementsByxxx() won't work. It would be nice Element.select() can limit the query on the given element only. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a negation to only match the root element: `:not(*>*)` This means that the element in question must not have any direct parent. For example consider this HTML content:

```
<div class="test"><p class="test2">xxx</p><p>yyy</p></div>
```

If `e` is the outer `div` element:

```
!e.select("div:not(*>*)").isEmpty()    -> true
!e.select(".test:not(*>*)").isEmpty()  -> true
!e.select(".test2:not(*>*)").isEmpty() -> false
!e.select("li:not(*>*)").isEmpty()     -> false
!e.select("p:not(*>*)").isEmpty()      -> false
```

But unfortunately, the pseudo-selector `:not` does only modify the last selector:

```
!e.select("p,li:not(*>*)").isEmpty()   -> true
```

So, if you need to match multiple selectors at once, you need some logic around it, I guess.

I hope that is what you asked for.